# Are all spiders supposed to use +http in their user agent string?

Tags: http

Here are some spider user agent strings I've seen recently.  They all seem to include a URL prefixed with +:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; meanpathbot/1.0; +http://www.meanpath.com/meanpathbot.html)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

Is that just a convention that most spiders follow?  Or is it specified somewhere.  I couldn't find it.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "a URL prefixed with +http:", I'd call that "a URL prefixed with +".

Comment: Good point.  I changed the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a convention that *some* spiders follow.  There is no constraint on what people can put in a user agent header.

Take a look at [this list](http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/category/2/index.html) of user agents that contain "GoogleBot".  You'll notice that many of these don't contain "+http".